# How to display the result of stored procedure in the temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to display the result of a stored procedure in a temporary table.

I have the following code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertpropertylisting]
    @propertyname VARCHAR(150),
    @propertyaddress VARCHAR(250),
    @propertyprice MONEY,
    @availableunits VARCHAR(100),
    @propertyid INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO propertylisting (propertyname, propertyaddress, propertyprice, availableunits)
    VALUES (@propertyname, @propertyaddress, @propertyprice, @availableunits)

    PRINT @propertyname

    SELECT @propertyaddress AS 'address'
    SET @propertyid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT 
        @propertyname = propertyname,
        @propertyaddress = propertyaddress,
        @propertyprice = propertyprice,
        @availableunits = availableunits 
    FROM 
        propertylisting 
    WHERE 
        property_id = @propertyid

    RETURN @propertyid
END

CREATE TABLE #propertylisting
(
    propertyname VARCHAR(150),
    propertyaddress VARCHAR(250),
    propertyprice MONEY,
    availableunits VARCHAR(100),
    propertyid INT 
)

INSERT INTO #propertylisting
    EXEC [dbo].[insertpropertylisting] 

SELECT
    propertyname, propertyaddress, propertyprice, availableunits 
FROM
    #propertylisting

DROP TABLE #propertylisting
```

I am not getting the output as table.

Comment: You are getting an error, aren't you? Post it.

Comment: @EzLo..I am not getting the error...i am not getting the table as output

Comment: You are executing the SP without parameters, that has to throw an error. You also have a runaway SELECT in the middle of the SP that would make the `insert into exec` fail.

Comment: @chetankambli  from procedure 2 outputs are coming u want 2 in single table the you have to alter the procedure as i posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems that I can see:

- Not supplying parameters to the SP.
- Stand-alone `SELECT` in the middle of SP that you don't want (also a `PRINT`).
- The lack of a batch separator when issuing the `ALTER PROCEDURE` command.
- **You are assigning the values of the inserted row back to the variables and not actually selecting them back to the caller**.
- It's recommended to always include the column list on `INSERT` statements, and specially when doing `INSERT INTO EXEC`.

First make some changes to the SP; remove unused statements and parameters (including the  `OUT` property of the parameter since it seems you aren't using it). You can return inserted values with the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause of the `INSERT` statement, **including** computed and `IDENTITY` columns.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertpropertylisting]
    @propertyname varchar(150),
    @propertyaddress varchar(250),
    @propertyprice money,
    @availableunits varchar(100)
as 
BEGIN

    insert into propertylisting (
        propertyname,
        propertyaddress,
        propertyprice,
        availableunits)
    OUTPUT
        inserted.propertyname,
        inserted.propertyaddress,
        inserted.propertyprice,
        inserted.availableunits,
        inserted.property_id -- Can return IDENTITY and computed columns
    values(
        @propertyname,
        @propertyaddress,
        @propertyprice,
        @availableunits)

END
```

After you run this `ALTER`, you can bring inserted records with a `INSERT INTO EXEC`. Make sure to pass proper values to the SP.

```
Create table #propertylisting
(
    propertyname varchar(150),
    propertyaddress varchar(250),
    propertyprice money,
    availableunits varchar(100),
    propertyid int 
)

Insert into #propertylisting (
    propertyname,
    propertyaddress,
    propertyprice,
    availableunits,
    propertyid)
Exec [dbo].[insertpropertylisting] 
    @propertyname = 'Value',
    @propertyaddress = 'Value',
    @propertyprice = 999,
    @availableunits = 'Value'

select 
    propertyname,
    propertyaddress,
    propertyprice,
    availableunits,
    propertyid
from 
    #propertylisting

Drop table #propertylisting
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this first create temp table and then execute the `sql` procedure

```
  USE [Joins]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[insertpropertylisting]    Script Date: 1/29/2019 3:55:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertpropertylisting]
@propertyname varchar(150),
@propertyaddress varchar(250),
@propertyprice money,
@availableunits varchar(100),
@propertyid int OUTPUT
as 
BEGIN
       insert into propertylisting(propertyname,propertyaddress,propertyprice,availableunits)
       values(@propertyname,@propertyaddress,@propertyprice,@availableunits)
       print @propertyname
       select @propertyaddress as 'address'
       SET @propertyid=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

       SELECT @propertyname=propertyname,@propertyaddress=propertyaddress,@propertyprice=propertyprice,
        @availableunits=availableunits ,@propertyid FROM propertylisting WHERE property_id=@propertyid

    --   Return @propertyid u can write in selecting it self 




END

Create table #propertylisting
(
propertyname varchar(150),
propertyaddress varchar(250),
propertyprice money,
availableunits varchar(100),
propertyid int 
)
Insert into #propertylisting
Exec [dbo].[insertpropertylisting]
```